# Obter apenas a primeira ocorrência de R1: com regex

Tags: regex

Tenho o seguinte texto:

```
R1:C1[6]|R1:C1[12]-[P1_G]
```

Preciso obter apenas o primeiro `R1:`.

Eu tentei fazendo uma regex preguiçosa `R[\d+]?:` ,mas não obtive o resultado que precisava e não entendi porque não funcionou também.

Eu estou utilizando o https://regex101.com/ como engine pra testar essa situação que será implementada em C# depois.

Comment: Tenta `R(\d+):?`, sem a flag `g`

Comment: Eu tentei e não resolveu

Comment: 1- Dá pra simplificar para `R\d+:` (ou `R\d*:` se o número for opcional), [veja](https://regex101.com/r/UiRRFO/2). Ou ainda `^R\d+`, mas somente se o `R` aparece sempre no começo. 2- Qual linguagem/engine vc usou e qual foi o resultado? Geralmente as linguagens possuem opções diferentes para obter todas as ocorrências ou apenas a primeira ([veja aqui](https://regex101.com/r/UiRRFO/1/) a diferença para o link anterior), e ainda há engines que não suportam a sintaxe `\d`, então seria interessante vc **[edit]** a pergunta e colocar mais esses detalhes.

Comment: https://regexr.com/48m63

Comment: Só lembrando que se você quer extrair o valor você precisará criar um grupo de captura utilizando os parenteses: `(R\d+)`

Comment: Se foi o `\d` que deu erro, vc pode trocar por `R[0-9]+:` - ainda sim, não está claro se o erro foi que trouxe todas as ocorrências (e nesse caso, seria bom saber qual linguagem usou, pois em cada uma o jeito de fazer é diferente), ou se deu erro de sintaxe na regex, ou alguma outra coisa (ou seja, por favor clique em **[edit]** e coloque essas informações na pergunta)

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss Dependendo de como vc faz, não precisa do grupo de captura: https://ideone.com/ClBTOi (mais um motivo para [edit] a pergunta e colocar mais detalhes :-) )

Comment: @hkotsubo eu usei o https://regex101.com/ como engine. Depois vou implementar a solução em C#. Essa solução R\d+: funcionou, eu achei que precisaria utilizar o ?

Comment: No regex101 é só tirar a flag `g` (a bandeirinha do lado direito, logo depois da regex): https://regex101.com/r/sw0ryP/1/ - O `?` quer dizer "opcional". Mas se os dígitos são opcionais, pode usar `R\d*:`. O `+` quer dizer "uma ou mais ocorrências", e o `*` quer dizer "**zero** ou mais ocorrências"

Comment: Obrigada @hkotsubo eu não sabia desse detalhe.